# Represent a column other than x, y on plot using matplotlib, python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to make a simulation of some data and I want to display my points with different colors for different categories. I have three columns where two columns I am using are x,y and I want to use third column which has two categories to be reflected on my plot.

```
y = np.array(q)
x = np.array(p)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (18,18))
plt.show()

for t in range(6000):

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)  
for i in s[t:t+4]:   # s is a list that contains the third column
    if i == 'Match':
        ax.plot(x[i], y[i], 'bs')
    else:
        ax.plot(x[i],y[i],'ro')
```

Comment: Could you please post code for your best attempt? Thanks

Comment: @Irnzcig : Please see the code above and I think groupby can help but I dont know how to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, here is one using Pandas

```
#generate data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(100,2)), columns=['x','y'])
df.loc[:,'cat'] = ['Match' if np.random.randint(0,2)==1 else '-' for i in range(100) ]

plt.plot(df.loc[df.cat=='Match','x'],df.loc[df.cat=='Match','y'],'bs')
plt.plot(df.loc[df.cat!='Match','x'],df.loc[df.cat=='Match','y'],'ro')
```

Comment: Thanks @Diziet Asahi !